# Windows Workflow Foundation application migration to Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am looking for migrating an existing WWF (windows workflow foundation 3.0) to Cloud Azure. And it seems like this option is not possible in Azure as it supports only PowerShell workflows. There is no information from Microsoft which confirms WWF support on cloud.

Does Azure supports WWF(windows workflow foundation 3.0 or higher versions) . Another option may be to install workflow manager on a VM on cloud and migrate it. Please help .

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as WWF-as-a-service in Azure. So if you want to do a "lift-and-shift" migration of your existing WWF solution into Azure then you must host it 'yourself' in an Azure VM or a container (Azure Container Instance, AKS or Service Fabric).

Azure does provide [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/logic-apps/) especially designed for long-running flows. Other options can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use an Azure Cloud Service Project in Visual Studio and define the Workflow(s) as a "Web Role."

I say this because WF workflows are exposed as WCF Services, which can be defined through Web Roles.